# Asymptotically Efficient of the two

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have come across two variants of the same function and would like to know **which is more efficient asymptotically.**

**1. Linear**

```
long double power(int base, int pow)
{
    if(pow<0)
    return -1;

    int i;
    long double p;
    p = 1;
    for(i = 1; i<=pow; ++i)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

**2. Recursive**

```
long double power(int base, int pow)
{
    if(pow<0)
    return -1;

    switch(pow)
    {
    case 0:
        return 1;
    case 1:
        return base;
    default:
        return base*power(base, pow-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane my bad! The mistake has been corrected.

Comment: Here's another `int p;` --> `long double p;` have you tried some timing comparisons for yourself, or do expect us to do that?

Comment: You are not supposed to tinker with the code in response to comments, it confuses other readers. Just post a well considered question in the first place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not show any research effort by the OP.

Comment: I have just started with algorithmic analysis and also some programming in c. So I dont know what you meant by time comparison. After doing some basic analysis based on the number of steps in each functions I think the complexity is n. But, I am not very sure if it is correct.

Comment: Write a sample program that will throw the same sequence of a million psuedo-random tests at each algorithm and time each process.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I will be more carefull next time.

Comment: "which is more efficient asymptotically." -- Do you even know what this term means? If you do, then the answer should be obvious.

Comment: @JimBalter I have just started out to study algorithms and all is done through self-study. At this moment what all I might have learned might not be that clear. But that doesn't pull me back. I hope you understand.

Comment: It obviously does "pull you back" if what you "might have learned" is not "that clear". If it isn't clear, then you haven't learned it. If you cannot immediately answer the question you asked here, then you haven't learned anything at all about big-O. If you had, then it would be obvious to you that both of these functions are linear in respect to the value of pow. Or, if it isn't obvious, then manually count the number of operations that each function executes for different values of pow. That will help you a lot more than simply asking people for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of both the algorithms grows with the growing of `pow`. Without considering that both will overflow quite soon as the `pow` grows they take O(pow) time (so have the same asymptotic complexity).

In situations like this if you are interested in performance you should prefer iteration over recursion. To understand my claim think about what happens when you call a function: 1) you push a stack frame to hold function parameters and local variables 2) you execute the body of the function 3) you pop the stack frame and return. Recursion would **ideally** push `pow` stack frames and then pop `pow` stack frames on return.

I say **ideally** because in reality the compiler **may** optimize tail recursion (recursion where the recursive call is performed at the end of the function) and transform it in (almost) a loop. As compilers do not usually give guarantees on the performed optimizations you should prefer the iterative version if what you have in mind is performance.

Comment: @mziccard Thank you. Your answer perfectly cleared my doubts :)

Comment: As you metioned, there is no simple answer to that, but the OP has to time himself.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, but I didn't get you.

Comment: @AmitRaj: Which part of the sentence did you not understand?

Comment: @Olaf about timing. If you could tell me what you really meant I shall take care of it next time.

Comment: @AmitRaj: As suggested by others, too: just time the two versions using many iterations and divide by the number of iterations. Et voila: you get the time per iteration and can compare how both perform. If you vary optimization levels, too, you might even be surprised how things change.

Comment: I have timed both versions, 1 million was not enough, I timed 100 million pseudo random calls, and the second (recursive) example is slighty slower. that could be a result of the recursion needlessly checking the value of `pow` on every recursion (my max pow was 19).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much for your help. I will from now on time my programs for such cases.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The multiplication might inhibit tail-recursion. It might help OP if you state compiler and optimizations.

Comment: @Olaf your objection isn't even relevant since I ran the tests alternately interleaved in a loop (3 times each test), and ensured any optimisation strategies were presented a level playing field by using the result of `power` through another function to break each 100 million iteration loop in a way that would never happen and the compiler writers would not know. If they had, the execution time would be 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Sorry, if that was missunderstood as objection. It was just an additional information for the first sentence. For the latter, you just provided the information now. About completely eliminating the test loop by the compiler: I actually presumed you are well aware of this and set up the test accordingly - from your posts I think you very well know what you do.

Comment: @Olaf thanks, just to be sure I ran the test again without calling the `power` functions within the loops: very similar but quite short execution time (about 0.25 seconds each, as opposed to 14 - 17 seconds), showing the loops were not optimised out.

Comment: This discussion is pretty clueless. Tail recursion, optimization, and raw times are irrelevant to the OP's question. The only relevant question is the relation between `pow` and the time taken ... which in both cases is linear."As you metioned, there is no simple answer to that, but the OP has to time himself." -- No, that's the opposite of what mziccard mentioned. What he mentioned, which is all that is relevant, is "they take O(pow) time (so have the same asymptotic complexity)".

Comment: " if what you have in mind is performance" -- What the OP has in mind is computational complexity. The discussion of performance details is a red herring.

Comment: @JimBalter I discussed computational complexity at the beginning of my answer. Since it is the same I gave some details on performance that I thought were interesting. Read the answer carefully and feel free to downvote it if you think it was misleading.

Comment: @JimBalter: As both have the same complexitiy and OP asks very well about performance, I would assume he very well means execution time. This is the reason, why I actually told him to time himself, as his environment is likely different from any of ours, although I find WeatherVane's information interesting. This sound to me like the classical _computer sience_ vs. _engineering_ discussion, IOW: theory against practice.

Comment: Sorry, it was "efficency", not performance. So it could very well be enegergy consumption, too.

Comment: @JimBalter so sorry to get your goat. I would have posted my timing answer if the question had not been closed. I prefer the empirical approach, observing what actaully happens, although other commenters like to quote standards and theoretical analysis.

Comment: @Olaf  "As both have the same complexitiy" -- that was the question. "and OP asks very well about performance" -- no, he didn't. " So it could very well be enegergy consumption, too." -- uh, no ... "asymptotic" tells us that it's all about computational complexity.

Comment: @JimBalter: can you please cite where exactly where OP asks about "complexity" in the question? I might have missed that sentence. I only read about "asymptotic efficiency", which can have various meanings.

Comment: @Olaf I guess you don't know what the word "about" means. Also, that close vote was completely unwarranted. I'm done with this discussion.

Comment: " I discussed computational complexity at the beginning of my answer." -- uh, yes, I quoted you. "Read the answer carefully" -- I've already done that.   "feel free to downvote it if you think it was misleading" -- that's not needed.

Comment: @JimBalter: I'll leave it at that, before you get more  personal - again. I do not care about your assumptions about (!) my languaage skills. I prefer to imagine this is a free world. Feel free not to vote to close.